# Add elements of string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a file who has two columns with numbers. I want to sum all elements of each column. I tried splitting that file using:

```
for line in f:
line=line.strip()
tokens=line.split()
```

Then I tried to convert each column token[0] and token[1] to integers using:

```
a=int(token[0]) 
print a
```

But I cannot access each element of this column. For example print command

prints

```
10
12
```

so I cannot select these values in order to sum them.

Moreover, I tried using print`(type (a) == int)` and I get

```
true
true
```

Is there a way to do something about that?

Comment: Please show your real code, real input, and real output. There is no way Python is printing `10 12` for `print a`. There is no way it's printing `true true` for anything. Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for what makes a useful question.

Comment: This is especially important in a case like this. Assuming the first line in the file is, say, `10 12\n`, your code will set `a` to the number `10`, and it will print out `10` on a line by itself. So, presumably there's something wrong in some _other_ code that you haven't shown us. (For example, maybe you're just doing `a=int(token[0])`, `b=int(token[1])`, and `print a, b` and not understanding that you don't actually have a problem; `a` and `b` are in fact numbers, that you can add to running totals just fine.)

Comment: I just edited to make it more clear. The output is
10 \n
12

and 

true \n
true

respectively

Comment: I don't believe that's your output. Python does not print `true` when you print out a `True` value. Why can't you just copy and paste, instead of trying to fake it from memory? And do that with your code, as well, so we don't have to guess whether any of your indentation errors are part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the code you've shown us, and fix the obvious indentation error, and add the obvious missing line:

```
for line in f:
    line=line.strip()
    tokens=line.split()
    a=int(tokens[0])
    b=int(tokens[1])
```

At this point, you have two numbers. You're done with that part of the problem.

If you want to *use* them for something, you can't just `print` them out, you have to… well, *use* them. For example, you can append them to lists:

```
a_list, b_list = [], []
for line in f:
    line=line.strip()
    tokens=line.split()
    a=int(tokens[0])
    b=int(tokens[1])
    a_list.append(a)
    b_list.append(b)
print sum(a_list)
print sum(b_list)
```

… or just add them to some running totals:

```
a_total = b_total = 0
for line in f:
    line=line.strip()
    tokens=line.split()
    a=int(tokens[0])
    b=int(tokens[1])
    a_total += a
    b_total += b
print a_total
print b_total
```

… or anything else you want to do with them. The point is, you have to decide *what* you want to do with them, then write the code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using numpy's genfromtxt routine:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('inputfile.csv', delimiter=',')
sum1 = np.sum(data[:,0])
sum2 = np.sum(data[:,1])
```